# XML Configuration Equivalent of @EnableHypermediaSupport

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I was reading through an article on [REST API development with Spring-HATEOAS](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/09/30/rest-hypermedia/), as well as browsing the [project page and docs](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/), but have so far only seen example code using Java configuration.  Is there an XML equivalent to `@EnableHypermediaSupport` and the configuration seen in the article's example?

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableHypermediaSupport
class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer c) {
        c.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() { .. }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is none. Feel free to open a ticket in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues).